# Shape.contains delivers inconsistent results

Tags: javafx-8

When using .contains for shapes in JavaFx I get different results depending on whether the shape is part of a group or not.

For example I create a circle, and stroke it using a graphics context.  If I then check a mouse press against the contains method for the circle it works as expected.  If I then add the circle to the same group as the canvas and click inside the circle it no longer reports any hits within the circle.  So basically it seems contains is only working if the circle is not part of a group.

I have tried this with other shapes and get the same basic behavior.  I have tried using the events screenX and screenY but these also do not work.

```
protected final VBox vBox;
protected final Button button;
protected final Canvas canvas;
private final Circle circle;
private boolean grouped;
private final Group group;
private Scene scene;

public ContainsTestBase() {

    vBox = new VBox();
    button = new Button();
    canvas = new Canvas();
    group = new Group();

    setId("AnchorPane");
    setPrefHeight(400.0);
    setPrefWidth(600.0);

    AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
    AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(vBox, 0.0);
    vBox.setLayoutX(228.0);
    vBox.setLayoutY(75.0);
    vBox.setPrefHeight(400.0);
    vBox.setPrefWidth(600.0);

    button.setMnemonicParsing(false);
    button.setOnAction(this::onTestClicked);
    button.setText("Test");

    canvas.setHeight(375.0);
    canvas.setWidth(600.0);
    group.getChildren().add(canvas);

    vBox.getChildren().add(button);
    vBox.getChildren().add(group);
    getChildren().add(vBox);

    circle = new Circle(250,250,25);
    circle.setFill(Color.AQUA);
    drawCircle();

    canvas.setOnMousePressed((e)->mouseClicked(e));
}


protected  void onTestClicked(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent)
{
    if(grouped)
    {
        group.getChildren().remove(circle);
        grouped = false;
    }
    else
    {
        group.getChildren().add(circle);
        grouped = true;
    }

    canvas.requestFocus();
}

private void drawCircle()
{
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.getGraphicsContext2D().strokeOval(circle.getCenterX() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getCenterY() - circle.getRadius(), circle.getRadius() * 2, circle.getRadius() * 2);
}

private void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
{
     //Note I have also tried sceneX and sceneY with each of these 
     //options and in each case if the circle was part of a group the
     // contains method failed

    //works only if circle is not part of group
    if (circle.contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
    {
        System.out.print("Mouse clicked in circle\n");
    }

    //works only if circle is not part of group- same results as above
    if (circle.getBoundsInParent().contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
    {
       System.out.print("Mouse clicked in circle\n");
    }

   //works only if circle is not part of group- same results as above
    if (circle.getBoundsInLocal().contains(e.getX(), e.getY()))
    {
        System.out.print("Mouse clicked in circle\n");
    }
}
```